# $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}P(X\geq n)<\infty$

Tags: probability

Let $\log^+(x)$ denote $\max(0,\log x)$. Suppose the random variable $X$ satisfies $P(X > 0) = 1$. Show that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}P(X\geq n)<\infty\qquad~\rm if~and~only~if~E(\log^+(X))<\infty
$$
I know $E(\log^+(X))=\int_0^\infty P(\log^+(X)\geq y)dy$. But it seems hard to find ties with the given form in the problem. Please give me some ideas to move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $log^{+}(x)\geq y$ for $y\geq 0$ is equivalent to $x\geq e^{y}$. Take $t=e^{y}$ then $dt/t=dy$. Hence your integral can be reformulated as
\begin{equation}
\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{t}P(X\geq t)dt<\infty.
\end{equation}
We can see now the connection with the integral test as $f(t)=\frac{1}{t}P(X\geq t)$ is decreasing with $t$.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Integral_test

Answer (score 0):

Note that $E[\log^+(X)]<\infty$ if and only if $E[\log^+(\lfloor X \rfloor)]<\infty$, because $X/\lfloor X \rfloor$ is bounded deterministically when $X \geq 1$.

Next, notice that $$\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} P(X \geq n) = \sum_1^{\infty} E\bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \cdot 1_{\{X \geq n\}}\bigg] = E\bigg[\sum_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot 1_{\{X \geq n\}} \bigg] = E\bigg[\sum_1^{\lfloor X \rfloor} \frac{1}{n}\bigg].$$ Since $\;\log N - \big(\sum_1^N 1/n\big)$ converges to a finite value as $N \to \infty$, the difference $$\sum_{n=1}^{\lfloor X \rfloor} \frac{1}{n} - \log^+ \lfloor X \rfloor$$ is deterministically bounded, which gives the result.